# PSPDFKit Cannot get document reference (although file exists)

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

First of all, I'm using version 1.10.2

I'm having problems to open a pdf document.

```
NSURL* documentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[loader getPDFResourcePath:file] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
PSPDFDocument* document = [PSPDFDocument PDFDocumentWithUrl:documentURL];

PSPDFViewController* pdfController = [[PSPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
[self presentModalViewController:pdfController animated:NO];
```

But I'm getting these error codes:

```
Oct 16 14:35:52 device-07 MODULESTEST[5150] <Error>: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15.
2012-10-16 14:35:52.217 MODULESTEST[5150:707] Error: -[PSPDFGlobalLock documentProviderForDocument:page:]/246 Cannot get document reference (although file exists) for /var/mobile/Applications/24968027-8B41-4B3B-937F-B9624F9661CB/MODULESTEST.app/buildresources/testbundles/bundle_one.bundle//activities/content_specifications.pdf
2012-10-16 14:50:10.038 MODULESTEST[5170:170b] Warning: __45-[PSPDFCache cacheDocument:startAtPage:size:]_block_invoke_0/1015 Document has zero pages. Not caching.
```

I've also used iExplorer3 and the file is present in the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm the developer of PSPDFKit.

The issue here is that you need to initialize your NSURL with *fileURLWithPath* instead of URLWithString. (Later one CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource fails with an undocumented error code that most likely means that it just doesn't support Web-URLs)